# Vscode is displaying random colours in the editing window

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, color-scheme

Not sure where to ask this question, however my Vscode is re-coloring letters and sections of my code seemingly at random. I'm not sure what is causing this issue and I aware that vscode does color variables automatically. Even so, you can see in the screenshot that even my commented code is randomly colored. Perhaps it is a extension that i have installed that is causing it, but I am a relatively new programmer so I do not know which extensions I am able to delete and do not want to jeopardize my code in any way. Any suggestions would be appreciated. TIA

[image: extensions that i have installed]

[image: random colored code]

Comment: disable them all and try again

Comment: I used the same extension as you, but I didn't encounter this problem, but I guess it may be related to the highlighting of the new version of vscode. You can try adding the line to your settings.json : "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false